# Grant VSTS user access to create new branches

Tags: tfs, azure-devops, tfvc

How do I grant a VSTS (TFVC) user access to create new branches from a branch? I already granted him "Manage branch" and "Merge" permissions on the ParentBranch.

When he tries to create a new branch named "ChildBranch" from "ParentBranch", he gets the following error: "TF14098: Access Denied: User  needs ManageBranch permission(s) for $/ParentBranchName/ChildBranch". Basically it's complaining that the user doesn't have "Manage branch" permission on the branch that doesn't exist yet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a folder, granting the "Manage branch" and "Merge" permissions on that folder. Then, as a matter of process, all new branches off of ParentBranch are created in that folder.

Answer (score 1):

I can repoduce the issue. Grant permission on **Root** repository resolved it.

Below structure for example:

- $/TFVC

  - -Main
  - -Test

If you want to branch from **Main**, then you need to grant the corresponding permission on both **Main** and **$/TFVC**

[image]

---

**UPDATE:**

> **Important**
>
> You cannot nest branches; therefore, you cannot convert any
>   folder to a branch if it either contains a branch or is contained by a
>   branch.
>
> *Source here : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/tfvc/branch-folders-files#convert-a-folder-to-a-branch*

So, you can only create a branch as I mentioned above.

However if you really want to create a branch under the **Main**, then you can **convert the Main branch to a folder** first, then move the branch to **Main**.

Follow below steps:

1. Branch from Main as I mentioned in previous steps (For example,
   **CTest** branch here).
2. Covert Main branch to a folder (Right click on **Main** branch -->
   Branching and Merging --> Covert to Folder)
3. Move the created branch (**CTest** branch here) to Main (Right click
   on **CTest** branch --> Move --> To Main folder )
4. Check in the changes

[image]

Comment: won't granting Manage Branch access on the root node allow the user to create new branches below it that are not children of Main?

Comment: @aobrientrin Firstly, **you cannot nest branches**, that means you cannot create the children branch of main under the **Main** branch. See the updated answer for more information.

Comment: Sorry for not being clear. What I really meant was that wouldn't setting those permissions on the root node grant "manage branch" access - through inheritance - to any new branch that's created going forward?

Comment: @aobrientrin Unfortunately you cannot create branch in your scenario if you do not grant the permission on root node. However you can create folder under the specific branch instead.

Answer (score -1):

We can grant access to user/user group to "Create branch", that can be provided by following below steps

VSTS -> select Project -> Project Settings -> Repositories under Repos Title -> Security -> Search for User or Group and Click -> Right side pane opens for configuring User or Group selected -> Create branch -> Change "Not Set" to "Allow"

[image: Allow Create branch]